# Block access to an IP

Tags: iptables, firewall, ufw

one of my applications is making connections to Google I'm not sure why. I verified this by looking at

```
sudo netstat -atupen

tcp        0      0 <local_ip>:36038    172.217.166.110:443     ESTABLISHED 1000       133785     6456/perl
```

Doing a `whois` against that gives:

```
NetRange:       172.217.0.0 - 172.217.255.255
CIDR:           172.217.0.0/16
```

I want to block all connections to and from that IP or IP range (172.217.0.0/16) such that no packets are sent or received.

How would I do this using UFW or IPtables and how can I verify that any IP in the range `172.217.0.0 - 172.217.255.255` is getting blocked?

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 ufw 0.36.

Comment: is this answer you question? <https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-block-an-ip-address-with-ufw-on-ubuntu-linux-server/>

Comment: @ johncli No I tried those the websits are still reachable if I type that IP on a web browser. I thought they shouldn't be reachable once blocked.

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1: How would I do this using UFW or IPtables?**
This answer is for iptables.

To block a range ip addresses DROP them early in the INPUT and OUTPUT chains, before any global ACCEPT.

Example:

```
#!/bin/sh
FWVER=0.01
#
# vxsa4_rules Smythies 2020.10.11 Ver:0.01
#       See here:
#       https://askubuntu.com/questions/1281796/block-access-to-an-ip
#
#       run as sudo on s18.
#
#       Note: These rules likely need to be merged with
#       any existing iptables rules set.

echo "Loading vxsa4_rules rule set version $FWVER..\n"

# The location of the iptables program
#
IPTABLES=/sbin/iptables

#Setting the EXTERNAL and INTERNAL interfaces and addresses for the network
#
# Set for Smythies (for testing). Edit for vxsa4 settings.
EXTIF="enp3s0"
EXTIP="192.168.111.122"

NETWORK="192.168.111.0/24"

UNIVERSE="0.0.0.0/0"

# Clearing any previous configuration
# Be careful here. I can do this on s18, but do not know
# about vxsa4's computer.
#
echo "  Clearing any existing rules and setting default policies.."
$IPTABLES -P INPUT ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -F INPUT
$IPTABLES -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -F OUTPUT
$IPTABLES -P FORWARD ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -F FORWARD
$IPTABLES -t nat -F

# Delete user defined chains
$IPTABLES -X
# Reset all IPTABLES counters
$IPTABLES -Z
# Smythies: While my references do not have it, I think this is needed.
$IPTABLES -t nat -Z

# Do not allow in any traffic from 172.217.0.0/16
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -s 172.217.0.0/16 -i $EXTIF -j DROP

# Do not allow out any traffic to 172.217.0.0/16
$IPTABLES -A OUTPUT -d 172.217.0.0/16 -j DROP

# At this point carry on. You need to merge this into your existing iptables rule set.
#
echo vxsa4_rules rule set version $FWVER done.
```

Resulting in:

```
doug@s18:~/iptables/misc$ sudo iptables -xvnL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 95 packets, 6543 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       0        0 DROP       all  --  enp3s0 *       172.217.0.0/16       0.0.0.0/0

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 60 packets, 6821 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       9      756 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            172.217.0.0/16
```

**Question 2: How can I verify that any IP in the range 172.217.0.0 - 172.217.255.255 is getting blocked?**
The above rules listing contains the packet/byte counters, and you can observe that 9 times the rule was triggered. Meanwhile, I had done this:

```
$ ping google.com
PING google.com (172.217.3.174) 56(84) bytes of data.
ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
...
ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
9 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 8230ms
```

I also had tcpdump running, before (as shown) and after (nothing outgoing, as expected) loading the iptables rules:

```
doug@s18:~$ sudo tcpdump -n -tttt -i enp3s0 net 172.217.0.0/16
[sudo] password for doug:
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on enp3s0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
2020-10-11 14:56:54.896447 IP 192.168.111.122 > 172.217.3.174: ICMP echo request, id 3, seq 1, length 64
2020-10-11 14:56:54.919209 IP 172.217.3.174 > 192.168.111.122: ICMP echo reply, id 3, seq 1, length 64
2020-10-11 14:56:56.381115 IP 192.168.111.122 > 172.217.3.174: ICMP echo request, id 3, seq 2, length 64
2020-10-11 14:56:56.404016 IP 172.217.3.174 > 192.168.111.122: ICMP echo reply, id 3, seq 2, length 64
```